# What is derived state in React, and why is it important?

Tags: reactjs

There are many answers online explaining why we [probably don't need derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), but what is it exactly? Where is it being "derived from"? Why does it matter, and how is it different from the correct way of handling state in a react app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Update July 2nd 2022 - In React Hook

We can use `useMemo` to have cache based reactive state.

e.g:

```js
const firstName = useState('John');
const lastName = useState('Doe');

// fullName will be re-calculated only when firstName or lastName changes
const fullName = useMemo(() => `${firstName} ${lastName}`, [firstName, lastName]);
```

---

Derived state is a state which mainly depends on props.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (props.value !== state.controlledValue) {
    return {
      controlledValue: props.value + 1,
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

In the above codes, `controlledValue` is a derived state which depends on `value` prop.

**Then why we avoid to use these derived states?**

The answer is simple: To reduce needless re-rendering.

In details, as we know, when any prop or state is changed then it will make the component to re-render. Then let's assume that `value` props is changed in the above codes, then it will try to re-render the component and also `controlledValue` state is also updated. That will also try to re-render.

So in fact, for only **one** update for a prop, but **two** re-renders.

**Example:**

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{this.state.controlledValue}</span> // same as this.props.value + 1
    </div>
  );
}
```

The two lines of output will be same, but when the prop is changed the component should be re-rendered twice.

But If we calculate output value from prop then, We don't need this `controlledValue` state. Then the component will be re-rendered only once.

Comment: This is imprecise. The purpose of derived state is to avoid needless re-rendering. It is used to cache performance-intensive data needed for rendering. That's why you would normally combine it with `shouldComponentRender`. For example, I have an app where we get a tree with thousands of nodes in props. We use derived state to cache the positions of the nodes. That way we don't have to recalculate everything if some other property (e.g. node content) changes. However, there are always other possibilities to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Derived state is a state that can be calculated from using the existing state.

For example if you have a redux slice which stores your weekly expenses.

```
store=[{id:1,task:"grocery",cost:120},]
```

at the end of the week you want to calculate the total weekly expense. You could keep another state `totalSofar` and everytime you add a new task you could add the expense to the `totalSoFar` but this is unnecessary. Because you would need the total cost only on demand, whenever you needed. ut for one time calculatation, you have to create a new state value,write extra code to  update this state value.

Instead, you could create a `button` to show you the `totalSoFar` and for the `onClick` handler, you could have a function that loop through the store array.

```
const totalCost = useSelector((state) =>
       state.tasks
      .reduce((acc, task) => acc + task.cost, 0)
  );
```

This might sound like a simple example but imagine in a large, complex app, you might need to derive too many different state values on demand. In this case, we keep our state as simple as possible and from those simple state components, we could calculate different states on demand

Sometimes you migh need to access to different slices of state, you use two different slices of state and you create a new `derived state`.